# Rendering texture from Mixamo DAE file

Tags: rendering, texturing, texture-baking

(I'm a beginner, please be kind)

I've exported a DAE file with textures from Mixamo and opened in Blender.

I can see the texture applied in Texture Paint mode, but can't figure out how to render or bake the texture on the model.

Based on everything I've found online, the nodes should look like the following:
[image: Screenshot of nodes in Blender 2.8]

I've tried putting the Mix Shader between BSDF and Material Output. And tried to switch Base Color with the diffuse node under it. But no results still.

But I just can't get anything to show in Render mode but a black model.
[image: Model renders black]

Am I close? Or have I missed the mark completely.

Comment: Is there any light source in your scene?

Comment: Yep, there's a spotlight directly above the model

Comment: hmm can you share a link to this model so I can check this out

Comment: Sure thank you: https://www.dropbox.com/s/w9w40nlkv9f9m9r/Mixamo%20and%20Blend%20Files.zip?dl=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After missing around with the material, couldn't really know what the cause of the problem really was.

But I got it to work, by deleting the material and recreating it again

just delete the material and create a new one

and this is the node set up I used

[image: NodeSetUp]

I used the Specular texture with the an inverter and connected it to the Roughness

you don't have to do that, that's just my personal preference. cause it's more true to a realistic shading.

I would like to suggest to use a Subsurface map too cause it would me the render a lot better.

Note : all texture have to be set to **Non Color** except the diffuse texture

Sorry I took so long to answer. I wasn't available the past few days. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same frustration that it still didn't work after reconnecting all the nodes.

The critical difference is the alpha value in the Principled BSDF node.

Blender viewport shading will render black if alpha == 0, ignore alpha otherwise.